# customizing webmail cpanel login area with php

Tags: php, email, cpanel, webmail

I have webmail setup similar to what hostgator has (I host with them and looks like they use their own system). I'm trying to customize the login page of webmail, but am a little stuck.

When you go to webmail page/port below, you get a **popup** login form, not a **web** login form. If you hit cancel, it finally loads the web login form.

[http://www.hostgator.com/webmail/](http://www.hostgator.com/webmail)

**Note that I'm using hostgator's webmail link just as an example because they use the same script.**

Is there a way through php (or any other way) to prevent the popup login form and go straight to the web login form? The next step would be to theme it, etc. etc. Any ideas or tutorials on how this script works?

Comment: Link provided doesn't work, it shows 404 NOT EXISTING page.

Answer (score 2):

You create an HTML page containing the form of your login.

In the form you must add the followig INPUT fields:

```
<form action="http://yourdomain:2095/login" method="POST">
   <input id="user" name="user" type="text" value="Write your mail here">
   <input id="pass" name="pass" type="password">
   <input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form>
```

**You must use the name provided: ('user' and 'pass')**

I'm not sure if form action should be simple "http://yourdomain:2095" without the "/login", you can try both.

Then you stylize your HTML page as you like.

In case you have a reseller account (I mean you can access WHM), on cPanel forum they say you can customize your webmail login page by using a functionality in WHM menu: "Server Configuration -> Tweak Settings".
I have never tried this, because they are disabled on my hosting, plz let me know if on your hosting they work. If it works this is probably th ebest way to go, because it would let you customize also the logout page.